# Всплывающая область при наведении на ссылку

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток

На некоторых сайтах, если нажать на картинку, то она увеличивается, без перезагрузки страницы. Вот интересует аналогичная конструкция. Есть ссылка (классно если при наведении на div тоже будет работать) **при наведении** ка которую охота всплывающую область, скажем 300х300 пикселей, что бы там можно было написать, что вздумается, как на обычной html странице. Вопроса 2:

1. Как это правильно назвать (для гугления)
2. Может ли кто привести подобный пример

p.s. Ну **если уж совсем прямо**, то если зайти на сайт первого канала, там сбоку от плеера будут ссылки на новости (их 4 штуки всегда), и вот если навести на них курсор - появляется такая область синяя. Вот что-то подобное. (Выдернуть из сайта нельзя, уже пробовал. Или выдергивать плохо умею)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Увеличение фото. jQuery](http://rche.ru/271_uvelichenie-foto-jquery.html)
- [Плавное увеличение картинки при наведении на jQuery](http://megaweb.su/31-plavnoe-uvelichenie-kartinki-pri-navedenii-na-jquery.html)

А в место фото можете вставить textarea, чтоб писать.

Comment: примеры хороши, к сожалению не понимаю как переделать их на свой лад. т.к. везде картинка превращается картинку, а хочется ссылка в часть страницы. Наиболее близкое только:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('.zoom1001').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true)
    .animate({width:"900px",height:"700px",left:"-300px",top:"-30px"}, 800);
    },
    function(){
    $(this).children('img').stop(true,true)
    .animate({left:"0",top:"0",width:"300px",height:"300px"}, 800);
    });
    });
    </script>
    // картинку обернуть в div class="zoom1001"

Comment: можно еще вот так http://habrahabr.ru/post/140522/

Comment: Интересная штука, вот только нажимать нужно для действия вкл/выкл

Comment: в ответ на Вашу правку вопроса. Если посмотреть код страницы первого канала то видно что изначально нужная вам область имеет стиль display:none;, затем при наведении мыши становится display: block; сделайте тоже самое у себя, в коде страницы заранее создайте нужную вам область и поствьте ее диву style="display: none;", а на событии мыши поверх нужного места настраницы меняйте стиль на display:block.