# Изменение свойств дива при наведении курсора

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток

```
<div style="...">наводим мышкой сюда</div>
<div style="display: none;">показываем это</div>
```

Имеем область при наведении на которую охота показать содержимое определенного дива. Причем таким образом, что бы див не сдвигал содержимое страницы в низ, а появлялся над областью на которую навели мышкой. Помогите реализовать задуманное.

p.s. [мой аналогичный, некорректно заданный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/132851/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение на css. Сдвиг влево и ширина указаны для красоты.

```
<style>
.tipped{position:relative}
.tipped .tip{display:none;position:absolute;top:-20px;left:50%;margin-left:-100px;width:200px}
.tipped:hover .tip{display:block}
</style>

<div class="tipped">
    <div class="tip">показываем это</div>
    наводим мышкой сюда
</div>
```

Comment: Или можно [чуть проще](http://cssdesk.com/gSBFG):

    <span class="tooltip"">Текст с пояснением</span>

CSS:

    .tooltip:hover:before {
      content: 'Всплывающая подсказка';
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: -25px;
      background: #fff;
    }

Comment: все гениально и просто. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо див с подсказкой обозначить как `position: absolute; z-index: 20;`, потом брать координаты нажатого дива с помощью `position()` и применять эти координаты к показываемому диву, попутно убирая стиль `display: none`

Comment: Зачем так сложно то ?

Comment: Чтобы можно было повесить красивых эффектов и прочего.

Comment: @shurik, в вопросе сказано:
 
> что бы див не сдвигал содержимое страницы в низ, а появлялся над областью на которую навели мышкой

Так что, @oburejin в правильную сторону шагает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоватся css, для этой задачи JS не нужен.

Собственно как то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/yraa6/)

Comment: да, но нужно место для того что скрыто

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [такой вариант (на jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/yraa6/2/). Подрихтуете CSS, эффекты и т.д. под свои цели.

```
<div class="target_obj">наводим мышкой сюда</div>
<div class="floating_object">показываем это</div>
```

**JS**

```
var flo = $('.floating_object').hide();
var tar = $('.target_obj');

tar.mouseenter(function(){
    var posTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var posLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    var minW = $(this).width();
    $(this).next(flo).css({
        top: posTop,
        left: posLeft,
        minWidth: minW
    }).fadeIn();
});

flo.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).delay(500).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: пример шикарен, в плане общего применения. конкретно под мою маленькую задачу, я ограничусь версией от ling'а. но этот безусловно возьму на вооружение. спасибо